# Log4net rolling daily filename with date in the file name

Tags: c#, .net, logging, filenames, log4net

I would like to have files named for example:

dd.mm.yyyy.log

How is this possible with log4net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4net appender filename issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833464/log4net-appender-filename-issue)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

In your Log4net config file, use the following parameter with the RollingFileAppender:

```
<param name="DatePattern" value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
```

Comment: Appears this has been promoted to a config element: <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />  Cheers!

Comment: @mstaessen `<preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />` is the correct syntax and this is a great answer. How did the loss occur, may I ask?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it went like this. On startup, log4net would generate the first filename in the rolling sequence. It would detect that that file already exist and would then decide to roll to the second file, but when that one also already exists, it does not decide to roll but instead clears it and overwrites everything in that second log file. It goes by totally unnoticed until you need logs of the cleared timeframe...

Answer (score 233):

```xml
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <file value="logs\" />
  <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: I think you should highlight the main point of what parameter to solve the problem as @Mun did. However, I also voted up for your answer.

Comment: It was the datePattern element, in conjunction with the staticLogFileName element (and note the value attribute for the file element) that worked for me

Comment: The complete answer!

Comment: Note that the accepted configuration here will result in log files for the current date getting overwritten if the application is restarted.  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LOG4NET/issues/LOG4NET-672 for a VERY similar issue, although it doesn't solve this.  

For this to work as desired, the file extension must be moved from the datePattern element to the file element ex:
  <file value="logs\.log" />
  <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy" />

Comment: The above comment may only apply when <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" /> is set.

Answer (score 33):

For a RollingLogFileAppender you also need these elements and values:

```
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<staticLogFileName value="false" />
```

Comment: This works, but appends the date after the file extension. For example I get log files like Error.log20111104 - Does anyone know of a way to format the file name a little better?

Comment: Here's how to format the file name better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615092/log4net-rolling-file-appender-define-extension/615137#615137

Comment: what is staticLogFileName used for? I only want the log file to be rolled into a new name after the day ends. I want to use a log monitor that looks at a specific each time.

Answer (score 28):

I ended up using (note the '.log' filename and the single quotes around 'myfilename_'):

```
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="'myfilename_'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\\Logs\\.log" />
```

This gives me:

```
myfilename_2015-09-22.log
myfilename_2015-09-23.log
.
.
```

Comment: `preserveLogFileNameExtension` doesn't work for earlier versions of log4net (e.g. v1.2.10) as it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276647/log4net-preservelogfilenameextension-not-working)

Answer (score 24):

Using Log4Net 1.2.13 we use the following configuration settings to allow date time in the file name.

`<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="E:/logname-%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" />`

Which will provide files in the following convention: `logname-2015-04-17.txt`

With this it's usually best to have the following to ensure you're holding 1 log per day.

```
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
```

If size of file is a concern the following allows 500 files of 5MB in size until a new day spawns. [CountDirection](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.CountDirection.html) allows Ascending or Descending numbering of files which are no longer current.

```
 <maxSizeRollBackups value="500" />
 <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
 <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
 <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
 <CountDirection value="1"/>
 <staticLogFileName value="true" />
```

Answer (score 20):

I've tried all the answers, but there was always something missing and not functioning as expected for me.

Then I experimented a bit with the hints given in each answer and was successful with the following setting:

```
<appender name="RollingActivityLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\temp\LOG4NET_Sample_Activity.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <datePattern value="-yyyyMMdd" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

The issue with other combinations of parameters was that the latest file didn't have the time pattern, or that the time pattern was appended as **`.log20171215`** which created a new file time (and a new **file type!**) each day - or both issues appeared.

Now with this setting you are getting files like this one:

**`LOG4NET_Sample_Activity-20171215.log`**

which is what I wanted.

---

**To summarize:**

- Don't put the date pattern in the `<file value=...` attribute, just define it in the `datePattern`.
- Make sure you have the `preserveLogFileNameExtension` **value** attribute set to `true`.
- Make sure you have the `staticLogFileName` **value** set to `false`.
- Set the `rollingStyle` attribute **value** to `Date`.

Comment: You can also set rollingStyle to Composite, which rolls on both date and size.

Comment: Works great. I would also add in the summarize: Make sure you have the staticLogFileName value set to false

Answer (score 6):

To preserve file extension:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\\LogFolder\\%date{yyyyMM}\\SchT.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maximumFileSize value="30MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
      <datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: why there are `%date{yyyyMM}` and `value="ddMMyyyy" `? which is the effective date pattern?

Comment: I think datePattern is for the file name but %date{yyyyMM} is for the parent directory (I wanted it that way)

Comment: The datePattern attribute sets the rolling period for Date rollingStyle. See  https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html under RollingFileAppender. "For example, a date pattern of "yyyyMMdd" will roll every day. See System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo for a list of available patterns."

Comment: @rbuddicom yeah but the question is about how to preserve file extension.

Comment: I know, Allan questioned the purpose of 'value="ddMMyyyy"'. Your comment "I think datePattern is for the file name" is incorrect in that regard.

Comment: @rbuddicom The datePattern indicates the pattern (or frequency) to roll the file which will be mentioned in the file name (or parent directory name if you want it). If you check the example in my answer you will see that the file is `SchT.log` and with `<datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />` the files will be named for ex: `201801\SchT30012018.log`. Moreover, if you look closely to the comment you'll see that Allen Ruin asked why there are `%date{yyyyMM}` and `value="ddMMyyyy"` and which is the effective. I answered and explained the role of each pattern and specified that I wanted it that way.

Comment: @Fourat fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

The extended configuration section in a previous response with

```
 ...
 ...
 <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
 ...
 ...
```

listed works but I did not have to use

```
<staticLogFileName value="false" />
```

.  I think the RollingAppender must (logically) ignore that setting since by definition the file gets rebuilt each day when the application restarts/reused.  Perhaps it does matter for immediate rollover EVERY time the application starts.

Comment: For me, it wouldn't work without the <staticLogFileName value="false" />

Comment: me as well, had to set staticLogFileName to false otherwise it wouldn't log

Answer (score 0):

I moved configuration to code to enable easy modification from CI using system variable. I used this code for file name and result is 'Log_03-23-2020.log'

```
            log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
            Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)repository;
            PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
            patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date %level - %message%newline%exception";
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

            RollingFileAppender roller = new RollingFileAppender();
            roller.AppendToFile = true;
            roller.File = "Log_";
            roller.DatePattern = "MM-dd-yyyy'.log'";
            roller.Layout = patternLayout;
            roller.MaxFileSize = 1024*1024*10;
            roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 10;
            roller.StaticLogFileName = false;
            roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Composite;
            roller.ActivateOptions();
            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is that the way to changing "rollingStyle value" to "Date". The others things are look like fine.

```
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
```

The trick is hidden those four definitions:

```
 ...
  <file value="logs\" />
  <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  ...
```

This is my log4net configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <!-- Log4Net -->
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
        </root>
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="logs\log_" />
            <rollingStyle value="Date" />
            <datePattern value="yyyy_MM_dd'.txt'"/>
            <staticLogFileName value="false" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level - %message%newline%exception" />
            </layout>
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
                <levelMin value="INFO" />
                <levelMax value="ERROR" />
                <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
            </filter>
        </appender>
    </log4net>
    <!-- Log4Net -->
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, the solution was to modify the datePattern value like this:

```
<datePattern value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
```

Here is my appender:

```
<appender name="testAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file  type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="ApplicationLog" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<staticLogFileName value="false" />
<preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
<datePattern value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
<maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

My log file will be named:
ApplicationLog-2022-11-04.log