# Log4Net File Appender Not Logging

Tags: .net, log4net

my FileAppender isn't working. It probably isn't a permissions thing as I'm local admin.

I've enabled internal debugging and I'm not getting any errors or exceptions from log4net.

My config file is below.
Thanks

```
<log4net>
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
            <file value="C:\log-file.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
```

The code to log is effectively:-

```
public class Logger
{
    private static readonly ILog defaultLog;
    static Logger()
    {
        BasicConfigurator.Configure();
        defaultLog = LogManager.GetLogger("default");
    }

    public static void Log(string errorMessage, Exception exception)
    {
        defaultLog.Error(errorMessage, exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running your exe directly instead of through Visual Studio.  See if it gets created then.  Also, does the ConsoleAppender work?  What is the code you are using to call log4net?

Comment: @Matt the ConsoleAppender works fine. Running outside VS doesn't work either

Comment: @MattDawdy, one thing I should probably mention is it's forced to be an x64 application

Comment: Do you call the XmlConfigurator or just the basic configurator?

Comment: Just that basic configurator. I've just tried in AnyCpu platform configuration and it's not fixed anything.

Comment: @StefanEgli you cracked it. Calling the XmlConfigurator fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: @StefanEgli If you want the rep then you'll have to answer the question otherwise I'll mark someone else's answer as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your description I assumed, that you used the BasicConfigurator (supports only ConsoleAppender) instead of the XmlConfigurator. Switching to the XmlConfigurator should fix your problem.

Comment: In particular: '*The invocation of the BasicConfigurator.Configure() method creates a rather simple log4net setup. This method is hardwired to add to the root logger a ConsoleAppender. The output will be formatted using a PatternLayout set to the pattern "%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline".*'

(http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 main options to enable logging. Refer to the [Configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) manual for more details.

1. Use `XmlConfigurator.Configure()`
2. Add `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]` to `AssemblyInfo.cs`

BasicConfigurator.Configure() can only write to the console.

Comment: Cheers. was missing the gubbins from assemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 1):

have you tryede RollingFileAppender ?

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
  <file value="C:\log-file.txt" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this helper class

1) you can initiate as many appender you need across the applications so if one dll call other dll both can initiate appenders and both appends will work.
2) also you can close the appender and ( as in case of file appender) then send it as a email

```
Log4NetFileHelper log = new Log4NetFileHelper();
        log.Init(); //Initialize
        log.AddConsoleLogging(); //Add Console Logging
        log.AddFileLogging(Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, "BatchConsole.log")); //Add Console Logging
        log.AddFileLogging(Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, "BatchConsole_error.log"),log4net.Core.Level.Error); //Add Console Logging



public class Log4NetFileHelper
{
    private string  DEFAULT_LOG_FILENAME=string.Format("application_log_{0}.log",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMMdd_hhmm"));
    Logger root;
    public Log4NetFileHelper()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Init()
    {
        root = ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
        //root.AddAppender(GetConsoleAppender());
        //root.AddAppender(GetFileAppender(sFileName));
        root.Repository.Configured = true;
    }

    #region Public Helper Methods
    #region Console Logging
    public virtual void AddConsoleLogging()
    {
        ConsoleAppender C = GetConsoleAppender();
        AddConsoleLogging(C);
    }

    public virtual void AddConsoleLogging(ConsoleAppender C)
    {
        root.AddAppender(C);
    }
    #endregion

    #region File Logging
    public virtual FileAppender AddFileLogging()
    {
        return AddFileLogging(DEFAULT_LOG_FILENAME);
    }

    public virtual FileAppender AddFileLogging(string sFileFullPath)
    {
        return AddFileLogging(sFileFullPath, log4net.Core.Level.All);
    }

    public virtual FileAppender AddFileLogging(string sFileFullPath, log4net.Core.Level threshold)
    {
        return AddFileLogging(sFileFullPath, threshold,true);  
    }

    public virtual FileAppender AddFileLogging(string sFileFullPath, log4net.Core.Level threshold, bool bAppendfile)
    {
        FileAppender appender = GetFileAppender(sFileFullPath, threshold , bAppendfile);
        root.AddAppender(appender);
        return appender;
    }

    public virtual SmtpAppender AddSMTPLogging(string smtpHost, string From, string To, string CC, string subject, log4net.Core.Level threshhold)
    {
        SmtpAppender appender = GetSMTPAppender(smtpHost, From, To, CC, subject, threshhold);
         root.AddAppender(appender);
         return appender;
    }

    #endregion


    public log4net.Appender.IAppender GetLogAppender(string AppenderName)
    {
        AppenderCollection ac = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Appenders;

        foreach(log4net.Appender.IAppender appender in ac){
            if (appender.Name == AppenderName)
            {
                return appender;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void CloseAppender(string AppenderName)
    {
        log4net.Appender.IAppender appender = GetLogAppender(AppenderName);
        CloseAppender(appender);
    }

    private void CloseAppender(log4net.Appender.IAppender appender)
    {
        appender.Close();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private SmtpAppender GetSMTPAppender(string smtpHost, string From, string To, string CC, string subject, log4net.Core.Level threshhold)
    {
        SmtpAppender lAppender = new SmtpAppender();
        lAppender.Cc = CC;
        lAppender.To = To;
        lAppender.From = From;
        lAppender.SmtpHost = smtpHost;
        lAppender.Subject = subject;
        lAppender.BufferSize = 512;
        lAppender.Lossy = false;
        lAppender.Layout = new
        log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} %5level [%2thread] %message (%logger{1}:%line)%n");
        lAppender.Threshold = threshhold;
        lAppender.ActivateOptions();
        return lAppender;
    }

    private ConsoleAppender GetConsoleAppender()
    {
        ConsoleAppender lAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
        lAppender.Name = "Console";
        lAppender.Layout = new 
        log4net.Layout.PatternLayout(" %message %n");
        lAppender.Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.All;
        lAppender.ActivateOptions();
        return lAppender;
    } 
    /// <summary>
    /// DETAILED Logging 
    /// log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} %5level [%2thread] %message (%logger{1}:%line)%n");
    ///  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sFileName"></param>
    /// <param name="threshhold"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private FileAppender GetFileAppender(string sFileName , log4net.Core.Level threshhold ,bool bFileAppend)
    {
        FileAppender lAppender = new FileAppender();
        lAppender.Name = sFileName;
        lAppender.AppendToFile = bFileAppend;
        lAppender.File = sFileName;
        lAppender.Layout = new 
        log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} %5level [%2thread] %message (%logger{1}:%line)%n");
        lAppender.Threshold = threshhold;
        lAppender.ActivateOptions();
        return lAppender;
    }

    //private FileAppender GetFileAppender(string sFileName)
    //{
    //    return GetFileAppender(sFileName, log4net.Core.Level.All,true);
    //}

    #endregion

    private void  ConfigureLog(string sFileName)
    {


    }
}
```