# How can I log the events in log files based on program per execution and date format?

Tags: log4net

I am using following log4net.config file:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file value= " D:\Logs_Event\log_event.txt"/>
<staticLogFilename value = "false"/>
<appendToFile value="true"/>
<datepattern value = "yyyy-MM-dd"/>
<rollingStyle value="once"/>
<layout type = "log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
<conversionPattern
     value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger ==> %message%newline"/>
 </layout>
</appender>

<root>
<level value="ALL" />
<appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
<appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

When the application starts, I have to log all events in text files till the application ends. If the application starts  next time the events will get logged into another text file with the respective date format. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4net one file per run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048844/log4net-one-file-per-run)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `PatternString` option provided in `log4Net`.

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"
        value="LogFileName_%date{dd_MM_y(hh:mm:ss)}.log" />
```

check [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) for the date conversion pattern and [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.DateFormatter.Iso8601DateFormatter.html) for Date time formatter.

related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349613/5395773