# Sitecore Custom Log, how to write only one file per day?

Tags: sitecore, log4net, sitecore7.2

we have implemented a custom log and writing to a custom log file.
The Problem is, that the log is created several times a day with filenames like this:

```
MyCustom.log.20161208.165109
MyCustom.log.20161208.165845
MyCustom.log.20161208.175134
MyCustom.log.20161208.184432
```

The Definition is like this:

```
    <appender name="MyCustomLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/MyCustom.log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to configure, in order to receive just one file per day? Or in other words, WHEN does a new file get created?

Comment: Does it happen on your local environment or prod? Is your app pool recycled? As long as your application is not restarted, there should be only 1 log file if you don't use rolling file appender.

Comment: Thank you Marek for that hint, I did not know that there is a new log created every time the app pool has been recycled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore uses log4net as it's underlying logging framework, which means you can make use of any of the standard appenders. Although Sitecore have added a custom `SitecoreLogFileAppender` appender, you can instead simply make use of the `RollingFileAppender` and roll the log files based on date.

You can find samples in the [log4net config examples section](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#rollingfileappender) of the documentation.

Specifically with Sitecore, change the appender(s) to the following:

```xml
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
  <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd'.txt'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
```

Some specifics about the changes in the above configuration:

- `file` : The name of the file to log to. Note that we supplement this using below settings.
- `rollingStyle` : The format to roll each file on.
- `maxSizeRollBackups` : This has been set to 30 above, you can remove this node if you want. This value ensures that anyt logs older than 30 days get automatically deleted by log4net.
- `datePattern` : This sets the format of the date to roll the files on. Note that the file suffix is included here in single quotes. See this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255588/661447) for more details.
- `staticLogFileName` : If set to true then the latest log file will always have the same name, but note that due to your `file` value there is no file suffix.

The files will now be generated in format `log.yyyMMdd.txt` in the same log folder as before and not be subject to having different files generated per application restart/app pool recycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily overcome this problem if you override the standard behavior of SitecoreLogFileAppender and create a new CustomLogFileAppender class which is inherited from FileAppender. Unfortunately SitecoreLogFileAppender does not offer you the possibility to override only a specific method which you need to amend for your requirements. Therefore you need to copy all code from SitecoreLogFileAppender into your newly created file appender.

```html
namespace MyProject.Core
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Web;
    using log4net.Appender;
    using log4net.spi;

    /// <summary>
    /// Custom log file appender
    /// </summary> 
    public class CustomLogFileAppender : FileAppender
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The m_current date
        /// </summary>
        private DateTime m_currentDate;

        /// <summary>
        /// The m_original file name
        /// </summary>
        private string m_originalFileName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CustomLogFileAppender"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public CustomLogFileAppender()
        {
            this.m_currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The file.
        /// </value>
        public override string File
        {
            get
            {
                return base.File;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.m_originalFileName == null)
                {
                    string str = value;
                    Dictionary<string, string> variables = ConfigReader.GetVariables();
                    foreach (string index in variables.Keys)
                    {
                        string oldValue = "$(" + index + ")";
                        str = str.Replace(oldValue, variables[index]);
                    }

                    this.m_originalFileName = this.MapPath(str.Trim());
                }

                base.File = this.m_originalFileName;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes the path.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="part1">The part1.</param>
        /// <param name="part2">The part2.</param>
        /// <param name="separator">The separator.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Complete path.
        /// </returns>
        public static string MakePath(string part1, string part2, char separator)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(part1))
            {
                return part2 ?? string.Empty;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(part2))
            {
                return part1 ?? string.Empty;
            }

            if ((int)part1[part1.Length - 1] == (int)separator)
            {
                part1 = part1.Substring(0, part1.Length - 1);
            }

            if ((int)part2[0] == (int)separator)
            {
                part2 = part2.Substring(1);
            }

            return part1 + (object)separator + part2;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Appends the specified logging event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="loggingEvent">The logging event.</param>
        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            if (this.m_currentDate.Day != now.Day || this.m_currentDate.Month != now.Month || this.m_currentDate.Year != now.Year)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    this.CloseFile();
                    this.m_currentDate = DateTime.Now;
                    this.OpenFile(string.Empty, false);
                }
            }

            base.Append(loggingEvent);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens the file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
        /// <param name="append">if set to <c>true</c> [append].</param>
        protected override void OpenFile(string fileName, bool append)
        {
            fileName = this.m_originalFileName;
            fileName = fileName.Replace("{date}", this.m_currentDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            fileName = fileName.Replace("{time}", this.m_currentDate.ToString("HHmmss"));
            fileName = fileName.Replace("{processid}", CustomLogFileAppender.GetCurrentProcessId().ToString());

            base.OpenFile(fileName, append);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current process identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The process Id.
        /// </returns>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetCurrentProcessId();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the name of the timed file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Filename with timestamp.
        /// </returns>
        private string GetTimedFileName(string fileName)
        {
            int num = fileName.LastIndexOf('.');
            if (num < 0)
            {
                return fileName;
            }

            return
                string.Concat(
                    new object[4]
                        {
                            (object)fileName.Substring(0, num), (object)'.', (object)this.m_currentDate.ToString("HHmmss"),
                            (object)fileName.Substring(num)
                        });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified file name is locked.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Locked or not.
        /// </returns>
        private bool IsLocked(string fileName)
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(fileName);
                if (fileStream == null)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                fileStream.Close();
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;
                return true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Maps the path.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Mapped path.
        /// </returns>
        private string MapPath(string fileName)
        {
            if (fileName == string.Empty || fileName.IndexOf(":/", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0 || fileName.IndexOf("://", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
            {
                return fileName;
            }

            var index = fileName.IndexOfAny(new char[2] { '\\', '/' });
            if (index >= 0 && (int)fileName[index] == 92)
            {
                return fileName.Replace('/', '\\');
            }

            fileName = fileName.Replace('\\', '/');
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName);
            }

            return (int)fileName[0] == 47 ? SitecoreLogFileAppender.MakePath(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, fileName.Replace('/', '\\'), '\\') : fileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Please find more information here:  https://sitecore.unic.com/2015/01/27/create-a-single-sitecore-log-file-per-day