# Log4net Custom File Pattern and Folder Location in c#

Tags: c#, log4net

I start to use the log4net for my log file, then I want to save the file log base in the date, and I made a couple of research then my configuration looks like this, it's working properly but one problem remaining if not creating new file when the date change, did I miss something in my configuration?

Here is my configuration.

```
<appender name="AppLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:/ProgramData/AppTitle/Logs/Application/%date{yyyy-MM}/%date{dd}-log.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="20"/>
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d %-5p] : %m%n%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following link:
[Log4net rolling daily filename with date in the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165084/log4net-rolling-daily-filename-with-date-in-the-file-name)

There are numerous items which I can see is quite different. 
For Example you can try adding the below items and see if it works for you. Cheers